# Irish Lottery probability

Tags: probability

I'm currently trying to work out what the probability is of winning the Irish (daily) Lottery by picking two balls and am a bit stuck.

There are 39 balls in total, of which 6 balls are chosen as per The normal lottery. The player selects two balls, and if these are in the 6 chosen balls, they win.

In my head, I have the probability of these two balls winning as:

$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{39}{2}} = 0.02025\dots $$

Is this correct?

If so, am I right in saying that if I then put on 50 bets, that I am guaranteed to win? This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Your expression $\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{39}{2}}$ is correct. And you are right, buying $50$ tickets does not guarantee a win. An interesting question would be what is the minimum number of (well-chosen) tickets that guarantees a win.

Comment: Your calculation seems right, though it sounds wrong to have a lottery with a 2% winning chance. The prize can't be very big, then ...

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it sure that there is no 50 tickets that ensure a win ? I mean, it's possible that some kind of optimum solution exists...

Comment: The minimum *could* conceivably be $50$ or less. I have not done the calculation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I agree it seems highly unlikely...

Comment: I thought 'Irish lottery' is when you select a pint of Guinness uniformly at random, and one of them contains a blotter of acid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your computation are correct. And yes, 50 bets are not enough to ensure a win, because each one have a little bit more that $2\%$ chance of winning, but they are not disjoint (several tickets among your 50 can win at the same time).

To have a bound on the minimal number of tickets required to ensure a win, you can consider the problem as a graph problem :

1. Consider a complete graph (a clique) with 39 vertices and 741 edges.
2. Now suppose that by removing $n$ edges, you obtain a graph $G'$ that is $K_6$ free (without a clique of size 6). It means that by buying each $n$ tickets (one for each such edge), you're sure to have at least a win for any 6 balls chosen.
3. Use [Turan's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) to prove that $G'$ has at most 
   $\frac{4}{10}.39^2=608 $ edges. Hence you should remove at least $741-608=133$ edges

So to ensure a win, you must at least buy 133 tickets. This is possible if you create a [Turan graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $G'$ : Buy all tickets $(i,j)$ such that both $i$ and $j$ belongs to the same subset among the five next one :

$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\},\{9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\},\{17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24\},\{25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32\},\{33,34,35,36,37,38,39\}$

Comment: Thank you. Although Graph Theory is a bit beyond me, your answer did mention how each ticket are not mutually exclusive, and this was where I was going wrong. So, for two tickets it isn't simply 2p, it would be 2p+p^2 and for three it would be 3p+3(p^2)+(p^3). (Is there a nice way to write this for all possible combinations?)

Comment: @Michael There is no nice way, because it depends on the numbers on the tickets. For two tickets, it will be $2p-q$ (less than $2p$), but $q$ will clearly depends of the fact that the two tickets share a common number or not. With more tickets, more possibility of sharing, and it may become tedious to obtain a simple formula.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is horribly organised and unclear.

the amount of pairs of numbers per ticket would be 15, as you can pair the first number with any of the other 5, the second with any of the other 4 (as the pair of the first and second has already been counted) and so on.

so 5+4+3+2+1. you can use:

$$ n(n+1)/2 \\
5*6/2 \\
15 $$

The total number of combinations of possible pairs to make would be by the same maths $$38+37+36+... \\
(38*39)/2=741 $$

So therefore the number of tickets needed to have every combination of numbers would surely be $$ 741/15=49.4 $$
which would be 50 tickets? feel like i'm missing something out

Comment: No, consider for example the same problem with only 4 numbers and 2 chosen. Each number has a 50% chance of win, but if you buy only two numbers, you are not sure to win.

Comment: But with that you can only make one pair per ticket, so the maths would still work, or no?

Comment: In my example, the player only select one number per ticket. But you must understand that if different tickets can win at the same time, then you can't add the probabilities of winning of all such tickets.

Comment: Oh i misunderstood, Instead of doing (total pairs)/(pairs per ticket), you'd do (total numbers)/(numbers per ticket), which would be 4/2 so 2 ticket are needed to win, right? where am i going wrong?